# How to add id preix for field in activeForm?

Tags: yii2, active-form

i have two forms holds the same model attributes, since Yii2 generate the field id to be *ModelName-fieldName* so the field generated will be as follow:

```
<select name="Channel[channel]" class="form-control" id="channel-description">
```

i have tried to use *fieldConfig* in *Activeform* but it doesn't add the id to the field itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should simply use the third parameter of `ActiveForm::field()` :

> `$options` : The additional configurations for the field object.

e.g. :

```
$form->field($model, 'channel', ['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'channel-description']])
```

Read more about [ActiveForm::field()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#field()-detail).

But if you really want to add a prefix to all your fields ids, you should override `ActiveForm`.

Comment: this will generate the id over the field container to be like:
`<div class="col-lg-8 field-channel-description required has-error" id="mynewId">`

Comment: what i am looking for is to add prefix for every field id not field container, do you think i need to override the activeForm

Comment: i can use the second parameter for dropDownList and add 
`dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($channels, 'id', 'desc'),['prompt'=>'--channels--','id'=>'myOwnId']`
but in this case i will loose the Yii Validation

Comment: Answer updated. And just tried the validation with custom id, it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want save input id structure "{model}-{attribute}".

Use yii\helpers\Html::getInputId() for generate "{model}-{attribute}" input id and complete it with your custom prefix.

```
$form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['id' => 'custom-' . Html::getInputId($model, 'name')])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a custom `id` for the input element, you may need to adjust the [[$selectors]] accordingly.

```
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'regId',[
            'selectors' => ['input' => '#company-vacancy-regId'],
            'inputOptions' => ['id' => 'company-vacancy-regId'],
        ])->widget()?>
```